# Charge given to the electroscope

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

The question is:  What is the charge given to the electroscope? 
Also each ball has a weight of 25g.

[image]

Here's how I started. First I draw the scheme on the forces acting one one ball (I took the one on the left).

[image]

Now I write the equations along the x and y axis.

\begin{cases}
Tcos(60°)-F_{21},  & \text{along x} \\
Tsin(60°)-mg, & \text{along y}
\end{cases}

So  $T = \frac{mg}{sin(60°)}$

and (using Coulomb's law) $F_{21} = \frac{1}{4 \pi  \epsilon_{0}} * \frac{(Q/2)²}{(2*60*sin(30°))²}$

Now I just isolate $Q$ so I end up with:

$
F_{21} = Tcos(60°)\\
\Leftrightarrow F_{21} = mg*tan^{-1}(60°)\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{4 \pi  \epsilon_{0}} * \frac{(Q/2)²}{(2*60*sin(30°))²} = mg*tan^{-1}(60°)\\
\Leftrightarrow 9.0*10^9 * \frac{(Q/2)²}{(2*60*sin(30°))²} = mg*tan^{-1}(60°)\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{Q^2}{4} = \frac{mg*tan^{-1}(60°)*(2*60*sin(30°))²}{9.0*10^9}\\
\Leftrightarrow Q^2 = \frac{4*mg*tan^{-1}(60°)*(2*60*sin(30°))²}{9.0*10^9}\\
\Leftrightarrow Q = \sqrt{\frac{4*25*10^{-3}*9.81*tan^{-1}(60°)*(2*60*sin(30°))²}{9.0*10^9}}\\
$

Plugin this into [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7B4*25*10%5E-3*9.81*tan%5E%7B-1%7D%2860%C2%B0%29*%282*60*sin%2830%C2%B0%29%29%C2%B2%7D%7B9.0*10%5E9%7D%7D) gives : $5.632×10^{-4}$ but the answer in my book is $4.8×10^{-6} C$ (and there is only the answer, no explanations).

I tried to see where is my mistake but I really don't know so where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made two mistakes (highlighted in red below):-

$$\Leftrightarrow Q = \sqrt{\frac{4*25*10^{-3}*9.81*\color{red}{tan^{-1}(60°)}*(2*\color{red}{60}*sin(30°))²}{9.0*10^9}}\\$$

1. Instead of arctan, it should be $(\tan 60^{\circ})^{-1}$ i.e. tangent of the angle raised to the power of $-1$
2. The distance should be in metres (SI units) instead of centimetres, i.e. should be $0.6$ instead of $60$.

The corrected equation should be:-
$$\begin{align}Q &= \sqrt{\frac{4*25*10^{-3}*9.81*\color{red}{tan(60°)^{-1}}*(2*\color{red}{0.6}*sin(30°))²}{9.0*10^9}}\\&=4.7598\times10^{-6} C\sim4.8\times10^{-6}C\end{align}$$

Comment: Urg silly of me. I spotted the 60cm but not the tan. Many thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome.